# Is there a lite database in code sharing nativescript project?

Tags: angular, nativescript

I'm setting up a new code sharing project with nativescript. I have to develop an offline app for tablet and desktop.
Everything is ok for code sharing (https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-sharing/), now it's time to talk about database.

I found the nativescript-sqlite plugin, but seems only works with nativescript and not with the web app.
I can not find a package (for sqlite, couchbase, mango, or other...) that works with native and with angular for the webapp.

Is there a package, a way to do this ? Or I have to play with json file (with edit-json-file package for example).

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use SQLite / Couchbase etc., you will probably have to write your own wrapper class that will internally load appropriate plugins / modules for the platform.

There is a old library named [sculejs](https://github.com/deyles/sculejs) which might also be suitable for your requirement. It supports multiple platforms like Browser, NodeJS, Titanium etc., I added NativeScript support by implementing [NativeScriptDiskStorageEngine](https://github.com/deyles/sculejs/blob/master/lib/com.scule.js#L5161) which does nothing but read / write the file using NativeScript File System apis. I'm unsure whether it works with latest version of NativeScript still, but it will be matter of minutes if you want to implement your own `DiskStorageEngine` in your project.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Manoj.
Not really solutions after a lot of research, so I tried with edit-json-file package. It will be enough for our project.
Many thanks,